# Usage of Chrome extensions in chrome apps

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Will the chrome extensions work in chrome apps ? or is there any configurations needed to be added in the manifest file ?

Comment: Is there any virtual keyboard plugin available to be used in chrome app ?.

Answer (score 1):

No, a Chrome extension cannot affect a Chrome App - neither the app's own content nor `<webview>`-embedded content.

For instance, an adblock-type extension for a Chrome App is impossible unless the app itself implements it.

So-called [Hosted Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/hosted_apps) are an exception to this. They should be affected as normal.

---

This does not mean that extensions can't interact with apps at all - [cross-extension Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external) is still possible.

Comment: Thank you.

I was wondering if there is any way to integrate any keyboard extensions with chrome app.